# Extremely Long Prototyping Board for LED Strip

Tags: led, pcb

I'm interested in building very long led lighting strip. Does anyone know where to get a long, thin prototyping/matrix board(if they even exist)? I can't think of a good approach for mounting/soldering two dozen leds(each with its own resistor) in parallel, spaced 2" apart. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you buy strips of LEDs like that off the shelf?

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm a cheapskate and avid DIYer. I could get the led strips, but I'd be giving up extra cash and the satisfaction of making it myself :). I also might want to use this strip for animated/sequenced leds down the line using a elongated common-cathode type matrix.

Comment: Or simply do like those guys: http://www.designboom.com/weblog/cat/8/view/13427/light-painting-wifi-by-timo-arnall-jorn-knutsen-einar-sneve-martinussen.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

24 LEDs 2 inches apart, that's 46 inches (+ 1 solder pad :-)). The largest PCBs I've seen (minicomputer in the 80s) were 25"x25", and I don't believe that they're being made bigger than that. You'll have to construct the strip from several shorter pieces. Unless you wanted to leave them bare this isn't necessarily a problem, since the seams would be hidden from view.

Comment: [this service](http://www.europlacer.com/en/iineoverylongpcb.html) can populate oversized PCBs up to 1610mm long. It doesn't say where to get these, though...

Comment: Just a note: Standard SMEMA stencil frame for solder paste is 29x29 inch with printable area about 25x25.

Comment: You can buy "Vero board" (aka vector board aka ...?) in lengths up to about 18" from memory. Copper strips at 0.1" run along length. Cutting a piece of this into multiple strips is 'easy enough' (score between tracks with sharp knife or scriber, place over edge of bench with scribe line at bench edge, bend overhung piece down to fracture) - can clamp to desk and use piece of board to bend all at once to reduce chance of mis-fracturing if desired. 

Soldering a number of these together with links is trivially easy and can be as cosmetically nice as you can be bothered making it. QED.

Comment: Great info, thanks guys. 

Russell, I like the idea of using vero/stripboard, makes wiring much easier, I think I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 3):

If you want them 2 inches apart, you could punch the leads thru cardboard and solder them together with the resistors on the back.

If you're asking about off the shelf true prototyping boards, many of the common "solderless breadboards" can snap together to make any length and width you want.

However, with 24 LEDs spanning 4 feet, I'd want something more permanent.  I think the cardboard trick with maybe a wooden dowel glued to the back for stiffness would do it.

Comment: That's an interesting idea about the reinforced cardboard, I may give that a shot.

Comment: cardboard.. reminds me of when i was 12 years old.. heheh - good luck

Comment: @ppumkin, I used to build stuff that way in high school.  It's actually not all that bad as long as you aren't trying to do really high impedance.  This was all thru hole components, so you put the components on the top side, punched the leads thru the cardboard, and soldered things together on the bottom.  If clever and with good layout, you rarely needed wires, just solder the various leads together the right way.  For audio I'd add another layer of cardboard when done, then a grounded sheet of aluminum foil on the back of that.  It was a shield, not a ground plane, but helped.

Comment: A strip of plastic (Acrylic, perhaps) with machined holes would look a good deal better, and alleviate most problems with leakage currents in the cardboard.  It's hard to advocate for a cardboard solution...

Comment: @Kevin, yes that would be more robust.  The OP was aksing about prototyping though, which is why I suggested something quick and dirty and good enough.  For a final product I wouldn't want cardboard either.

Answer (score 2):

[All Flex claims](http://www.allflexinc.com/DesignGuide/maxi.shtml) they can make flexible printed circuits 40 feet long.

Comment: OP probably doesn't need flex, but +1 for the ridiculous length (and the "longer upon request" :-))

Comment: Very cool. Could have good applications for lighting strips that need to contour along a curved shape or wall.

Answer (score 0):

The longest off-the-shelf protoboards I've seen are 17 inches long:

Keystone Electronics 3407: 17 inch x 2.73 inch (431.8mm x 69.3mm) Prototype Boards - Perforated (alas, it's just insulation with holes in it: no copper)

Injectorall Electronics B3429D: 17 inch x 5.75 inch (431.8mm x 146.05mm) Drilled Copper Clad Breadboard (completely covered with copper; you'll have to cut/etch a slot down the length to separate the LED terminals)

Vector Electronics 169P44WEC1: 17" x 4.5" (431.6mm x 114.3mm) Prototype Boards - Perforated; FR4 Fiberglass and Copper Clad, Single Sided, 1 oz. (completely covered with copper; you'll have to cut/etch a slot down the length to separate the LED terminals)

I'm pretty sure they're all available from Mouser, Newark, or Digikey.